# To show the group $Aut(V)$ of algebra automorphisms of a finite dimensional algebra $V$ is a Zariski closed subgroup of $GL(V )$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras, tangent-spaces

My aim is to proceed with a Heuristic calculation of the Tangent space to Aut(V) at the identity. However, I will have to prove the problem statement before I can proceed with that.

My problem, Understanding the polynomial structure on the group Aut(V).
The proper way of doing that would have to do with the symmetric algebra on the dual space, I don't wish to proceed this way.

And I have been told to visualize the "coordinates" of the matrices as polynomials and work with that. If that is so, what would it mean for the "coordinate" to be "zero". Once this is certified I can proceed. This is what I have thought.

Any other procedure, please, please let me know.

Comment: What's the difference between GL($V$) and Aut($V$)?

Comment: $Aut(V)$ preserves the multiiplication.

Comment: Calculating the tangent space won’t help you at all. The point is that the multiplication on the algebra is (bilinear, hence) polynomial, so the condition that it be preserved is a polynomial condition. This is easiest to see by writing everything out in coordinates but it’s not strictly necessary.

Comment: This might be useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3832426/automorphism-group-of-finite-k-algebra-as-an-affine-variety

Comment: The link by Moises would seem to make this question an exact duplicate. Unless you have any objections, I will mark it as such soon.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much everyone.